# Update plugin from github

Tags: plugin-development, updates

I'm working on a WordPress plugin hosted locally on GitHub, and it includes several addons. When updating a specific add-on, I want to ensure that the main plugin is of a particular version before allowing the update. I have wrote the logic for this work but I am not able to test it because I don't have update option on my add on. To add update option I have used the code below but it didn't work.

```
function check_for_plugin_update($transient) {
   $github_username = 'username';
   $github_repo = 'repo_name';
   $access_token = 'access_token'; 
 
    if (empty($transient->checked)) {
        return $transient;
    }

    // Get the current version of your plugin
    $current_version = '1.3.1'; // Replace with your current version

    // Get the latest release from GitHub
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{$github_username}/{$github_repo}/releases/latest";
    if ($access_token) {
        $url = add_query_arg('access_token', $access_token, $url);
    }

    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $data = json_decode($body);

        // Compare versions
        if ($data && version_compare($current_version, $data->tag_name, '<')) {
            $transient->response[plugin_basename(__FILE__)] = (object) array(
                'new_version' => $data->tag_name,
                'package' => $data->zipball_url,
                'url' => $data->html_url
            );
        }
    }

    return $transient;
}
 
add_filter('pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', 'check_for_plugin_update');
```